# Need Conceptual Help Rendering a Heat Map

Tags: java, android, graphics, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to create a heatmap for android google maps. I have geolocation and points that have negative and positive weight attributed to them that I would like to visually represent. Unlike the majority of heatmaps, I want these positive and negative weights to destructively interfere; that is, when two points are close to each other and one is positive and the other is negative, the overlap of them destructively interferes, effectively not rendering areas that cancel out completely. 
I plan on using the android google map's TileOverlay/TileProvider class that has the job of creating/rendering tiles based a given location and zoom. (I don't have an issue with this part.)

How should I go about rendering these Tiles? I plan on using java's Graphics class but the best that I can think of is going through each pixel, calculating what color it should be based on the surrounding data points, and rendering that pixel. This seems very inefficient, however, and I was looking for suggestions on a better approach.

Edit: I've considered everything from using a non-android Google Map inside of a WebView to using a TileOverlay to using a GroundOverlay. What I am now considering doing is having a large 2 dimensional array of "squares." Each square would have a long, lat, and total +/- weights. When a new data point is added, instead of rendering it exactly where it is, it will be added to the "square" that it is in. The weight of this data point will be added to the square and then I will use the GoogleMap Polygon object to render the square on the map. The ratio of +points to -points will determine the color that is rendered, with a ratio closer to 1:1 being clear, >1 being blue (cold point), and <1 being red (hot point).
Edit: a.k.a. clustering the data into small regional groups

Comment: Have you looked at this project: https://code.google.com/p/mapex/

Comment: Yes, I have. It doesn't look like it supports the v2 api or destructively interfering points, which is what I needed help with.

Comment: Did you mean `Android's Canvas` instead of `java's Graphics`?

Comment: No, I was going to use Java's Graphics class to create a bitmap image, convert this image to a byte arrray, and use this byte array to render the tile (it requires a byte[]). (But now see the edit.)

Comment: So you want to do it on a server?

Comment: No, the points would be user generated and displayed graphically on an android map. No server would be required as the data would be saved locally.

Comment: And how do you want to use `Graphics` class on Android devices?

Comment: I would create a new BufferedImage, obtain a Graphics object from it, then use the Graphics' functions such as drawRect(), etc to form the image, and then use bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getData() to obtain a byte array which I would use to create a Tile object. But now I am considering instead doing the idea in the edit of the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest trying

> going through each pixel, calculating what color it should be based on the surrounding data points, and rendering that pixel.

Even if it slow, it will work. There are not too many `Tiles` on the screen, there are not too many pixels in each `Tile` and all this is done on a background thread.

All this is still followed by translating `Bitmap` into `byte[]`. The `byte[]` is a representation of PNG or JPG file, so it's not a simple pixel mapping from `Bitmap`. The last operation takes some time too and may possibly require more processing power than your whole algorithm.

Edit (moved from comment):

What you describe in the edit sounds like a simple clustering on LatLng. I can't say it's a better or worse idea, but it's something worth a try.

Comment: Do you think that the option in the edit would be a better idea? It would obviously render things in a blocky/pixelated manner but it would be far more efficient. If I wanted the range of a data point to be farther than the "square" that it is currently in then I could extend it by adding weights to adjacent squares.

Comment: @ReedB I think that after asking 7 questions in the last 2 weeks on the same topic, it is a good time to write some code. You will have many problems, which make good questions. What you describe in the edit sounds like a simple clustering on LatLng. I can't say it's a better or worse idea, but it's something worth a try.

Comment: Okay, I will try this approach first. As I increase the number of clusters, the rendering will look better but this will put a higher strain on the processor. I will test different clustering levels and see how it goes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am going to start with squares because they will be the easiest to conceptualize (take latitude, add 90, multiply by x/180 where x-by-x is the dimension of the cluster grid that I want, then I have the upper left coordinate that the square should be rendered at, etc). Also, the GoogleMap Polygon object is rendered like a spherically-wrapped square, that is, it technically isn't a square but the sides are equal angles away from the horizon.

Comment: Just an update: there are severe memory issues encountered by using this method in both the rendering of the squares and in the array used to store the squares. Without the array, the upper limit for how many squares can be rendered seems to be around 3k-4k. After this, the program runs out of memory. Additionally, I have been using a large two-dimensional array to store either null, if no data has been entered in that specific square, or a custom square class containing the weight data. Having all of this excess null data pushed onto the stack at runtime is very costly so ... (cont)

Comment: (cont) ... I plan on implementing a BST containing a comparable BST containing squares. The outer-most BST would compare the inner BSTs based on their latitudes. The inner BSTs would compare the squares by their longitudes. This sounds complicated but it simply is a two-dimensional dynamically allocated ordered list. This would only make the structure take up space for squares that currently exist and not waste memory on ones that haven't been yet instantiated. I will provide another update once I have implemented this.